# Diagrams with stacked labels and boxes

Tags: diagrams, boxes, stack

I am trying to draw the following diagrams in LaTeX (these arise in linear coding theory and group theory with reference to the Golay code). Following are the excerpts from the book 'Twelve sporadic groups' by Griess, and I want to create the two diagram visible on the following two pages. I am new to LaTeX so any help would be highly appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with a simple `array` environment, or with `blkarray`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array, amsmath,  blkarray, hhline}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
<-6> mathx5 <6-7> mathx6 <7-8> mathx7
<8-9> mathx8 <9-10> mathx9
<10-12> mathx10 <12-> mathx12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\widebar}{0}{mathx}{"73}


\begin{document}

\[%
  \begin{array}{l*{3}{|>{ \cdot }c>{ \cdot }c}|}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{6} \\%
    \cline{2-7}
    0                    &                       &                       &                       &                       &                       &                       \\
    1                    &                       &                       &                       &                       &                       &                       \\
    \omega               &                       &                       &                       &                       &                       &                       \\
    \bar{\omega }         &                       &                       &                       &                       &                       &                       \\
    \cline{2-7}
  \end{array}%
  \qquad
  \begin{array}{l*{3}{|cc}|}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{6} \\%
    \cline{2-7}
    0                    &  \circ                 &  \circ                 &                       &                       &                       &  \circ                 \\
    1                    &                       &  \circ                 &  \circ                 &  \circ                 &                       &  \circ                 \\
    \omega               &                       &                       &                       &  \circ                 &                       &  \circ                 \\
    \bar{\omega }         &                       &                       &  \circ                 &  \circ                 &  \circ                 &                       \\
    \cline{2-7}
  \end{array}%
\]%`
\bigskip
\[%
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
  \begin{blockarray}{lcccccc}
    & 1 & 2 & 3 &  4  & 5 & 6 \\%
    \begin{block}{l*{3}{|>{ \cdot }c>{ \cdot }c}|}
      \hhline{~|------|}
      0 &  & & &  &  &  &  \\
      1 &  & &  &  &  &  &  \\
      \omega &   & & &  &  &  &  \\
      \widebar{\omega } & & &  &  &  &  &  \\
      \hhline{~|------|}
    \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}%
  \qquad
  \begin{blockarray}{lcccccc}
    & 1 & 2 & 3 &  4  & 5 & 6 \\%
    \begin{block}{l*{3}{|cc}|}
      \hhline{~|------|}
      0 &  \circ &  \circ & &  &  &   \circ  \\
      1 &  &   \circ &  \circ  &  \circ  &  &  \circ  \\
      \omega &  & & &  \circ  &  &   \circ \\
      \widebar{\omega } & & &  \circ  &  \circ  &  \circ  &   \\
      \hhline{~|------|}
    \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}%
\]%`
\end{document}
```

[image]